# Chronic ostracism/social rejection epidemiology

Tags: social-psychology, social-networks

I recently came across a paper ([Wesselmann, et al. 2015](https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00040)) about chronic ostracism. It seems a relatively new area of research and I'm sure it has its flaws as a model. Anyway, I had no luck finding an at least western world-wise study on the epidemiology and frequencies across regions and countries. By anecdotal and personal experience I have the suspicion that regional culture can influence and boost ostracism among the population by some amount but without tons of reliable data it's just a claim. Is there any statistical study about it?

### References

Wesselmann, E. D., Ren, D., & Williams, K. D. (2015). Motivations for responses to ostracism. *Frontiers in Psychology, 6*, 40. https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00040